# How to set ANDROID_HOME path in windows environment?

Tags: android, android-studio

Unable to set How to set ANDROID_HOME path in windows environment.

Please provide the steps.

Answer (score 3):

Steps already available on [Google](https://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-set-path-environmental-variable-for-sdk-in-windows/)

1. Click Start.
2. Right-click Computer, and then select Properties.
3. Click Advanced system settings.
4. On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
5. Under User variables, click New.
6. For Variable name, type the following value: ANDROID_HOME For Variable value, type the path to the parent directory where your Android SDK is installed.
7. For instance: C:\Android\android-sdk Click OK until you have closed all
   dialog boxes. Do not click Cancel.
8. Restart your computer.